# Magento 2, error in saving custom image path (external link) to product

Tags: magento2, product-images, controllers

Product image links are from third-party. Using below code in controller, I'm trying to save it for one product as a test. But no success and getting "image does not exist" in controller, however the link is fine.

```
$attributeImage = array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail');
$product = $this->productFactory->create()->load(2);
$imageLink = "https://link-from-thirdparty"; 
echo $imageLink;
$product->addImageToMediaGallery( $imageLink , $attributeImage, true,false );
$product->save();
```

Comment: I don't think this is allowed in magento, you have to copy the images on the server and then pass their path in above function.

Comment: Is it so?... not allowed!

Comment: yes it is not allowed